# Navigation Drawer from support library vs. design library

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design, android-support-library, android-design-library

As stated in the [Support Library Features](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) page; the **v4 Support Library** adds support for *Navigation Drawers* by adding a `DrawerLayout` and the **Design Support Library** adds support for Navigation Drawers by adding a `NavigationView` (as an addition to the `DrawerLayout` which it has as a dependency).

There are many tutorials how to create a Navigation Drawer using only the v4 Support Library, e.g. the [Google page on Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Since the Design Support Library adds support for API level 7, what is the recommended and preferred way to create a Navigation Drawer. Where are the differences? Are there design differences?

Comment: Really good question for beginners by the way.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the recommended and preferred way to create a Navigation
>   Drawer. Where are the differences? Are there design differences?

Actually, those are haven't any big differences.for example, As `Google` doc says:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

> For example, the following layout uses a DrawerLayout with **two child**
>   views: **a FrameLayout to contain the main content** (populated by a
>   Fragment at runtime), and a **ListView for the navigation drawer**.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But in the `Support Library`, you can achieve this easily with `NavigationView` of course with ***Standard Material Design guideline*** like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!--Contents like Coordinator Layout-->

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
    <!--Here is the Drawer menu-->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In this case, we used `app:menu="@menu/drawer"` with a simple and easy way to achieve that and in the above codes, they used `<ListView`.

That's all.

Comment: So the design library just adds a `NavigationView` as an additional element instead of a `FrameLayout` and `ListView`? That's all?

Comment: Adds `NavigationView` instead of `ListView`.and instead of that `FrameLayout`, you can use `CoordinatorLayout`, that depends on your expect(you can do it like `MaterialDesign` Guideline).Check this links for Support Library: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Answer (score 1):

The [NavigationView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) represents a standard navigation menu for your app and it follows the [Material Guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

`NavigationView` **is typically placed inside** a `DrawerLayout`.

Of course you can use your favorite layout inside the `DrawerLayout`.

More info about the `NavigationView` [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).

Comment: So if I follow the Material Guidelines I am better off with `NavigationView` since it already supports it, but if I want to build something differently I would go with a custom `FrameLayout` and `ListView` (I have to use `DrawerLayout` in both ways).